# MYSQL SUM until last day of Each month for last 12 months

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table like this two

Table A

```
  date          amount     B_id 
'2020-1-01'     3000000      1
'2019-8-01'     15012        1
'2019-6-21'     90909        1
'2020-1-15'     84562        1
--------
```

Table B

```
id       type
1         7
2         5
```

I have to show sum of amount until the last date of each month for the last 12 month.
The query i have prepared is like this..

```
SELECT num2.last_dates,
  (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM A
      INNER JOIN B ON A.B_id = B.id
      WHERE B.type = 7 AND A.date<=num2.last_dates
     ),
    (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM A
      INNER JOIN B ON A.B_id = B.id
      WHERE B.type = 5 AND A.date<=num2.last_dates)
FROM
  (SELECT last_dates
      FROM (
  SELECT LAST_DAY(CURDATE()  - INTERVAL CUSTOM_MONTH MONTH) last_dates
      FROM(
          SELECT 1 CUSTOM_MONTH UNION
            SELECT 0 UNION
            SELECT 2 UNION
            SELECT 3 UNION
            SELECT 4 UNION
            SELECT 5 UNION
            SELECT 6 UNION
            SELECT 7 UNION
            SELECT 8 UNION
            SELECT 9 UNION
            SELECT 10 UNION
          SELECT 11 UNION
            SELECT 12 )num
) num1
  )num2

ORDER BY num2.last_dates
```

This gives me the result like this which is exactly how i need it. I need this query to execute faster. Is there any better way to do what i am trying to do?

```
2019-05-31  33488.69        109.127800
2019-06-30  263.690          1248932.227800
2019-07-31  274.690         131.827800
2019-08-31  627.690         13.687800
2019-09-30  1533.370000     08.347800
2019-10-31  1444.370000     01.327800
2019-11-30  5448.370000     247.227800
2019-12-31  61971.370000    016.990450
2020-01-31  19550.370000    2535.185450
2020-02-29  986.370000      405.123300
2020-03-31  1152.370000     26.793300
2020-04-30  9404.370000     11894.683300
2020-05-31  3404.370000     17894.683300
```

Comment: How is your table indexed? Please show us the schema. At the very least you should have an index on all those columns.

Comment: index of A has date, id ,B_id  and index of B includes id and type both.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using? Such running totals are much easier to get with window functions, available as of MySQL 8.

Comment: Your result rows look a bit surprising. I expected the values to get bigger with each month, but there seem to be months with negative balances reducing the running totals. Then, *can* there be missing months in your table? (Otherwise the query in my answer would become way simpler without the need to create month rows.)

Comment: can you do in a stored procedure? Using a user variable to accumulate a running total would solve this.

Comment: its very unlikely there will be missing months in the data.. but yes it has negative values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd probably approach this in MySQL 8 with `SUM OVER`:

1. Get the last 12 months.
2. Use these months to add empty month rows to the original data, as MySQL doesn't support full outer joins.
3. Get the running totals for all months.
4. Show only the last twelve months.

The query:

```
with months (date) as
(
  select last_day(current_date - interval  1 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  2 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  3 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  4 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  5 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  6 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  7 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  8 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval  9 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval 10 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval 11 month) union all
  select last_day(current_date - interval 12 month)
)
, data (date, amount, type) as
(
  select last_day(a.date), a.amount, b.type
  from a
  join b on b.id = a.b_id
  where b.type in (5, 7)
  union all
  select date, null, null from months
)
select
  date,
  sum(sum(case when type = 5 then amount end)) over (order by date) as t5,
  sum(sum(case when type = 7 then amount end)) over (order by date) as t7
from data
group by date
order by date
limit 12;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ddeb3ab3e086bfc182f0503615fba74b

I don't know whether this is faster than your own query or not. Just give it a try. (You'd get my query much faster by adding a generated column for `last_day(date)` to your table and use this. If you need this often, this may be an option.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This worked perfectly.. wasn't familiar with window functions.Also this is way faster. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use conditional aggregation, and pre-aggregate the monthly totals in one pass, instead of doing twenty-six individual passes repeatedly through the same data.

I'd start with something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A.date < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -14 MONTH
       THEN LAST_DAY(     DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -14 MONTH )
       ELSE LAST_DAY( A.date )
       END                                    AS _month_end
     , SUM(IF( B.type = 5 , B.amount , NULL)) AS tot_type_5
     , SUM(IF( B.type = 7 , B.amount , NULL)) AS tot_type_7
  FROM A
  JOIN B
    ON B.id = A.B_id
 WHERE B.type IN (5,7)
 GROUP
    BY _month_end
```

(column amount isn't qualified in original query, so just guessing here which table that is from. adjust as necessary. best practice is to qualify *all* column references.

That gets us the subtotals for each month, in a single pass through A and B.

We can get that query tested and tuned.

Then we can incorporate that as an inline view in an outer query which adds up those monthly totals. (I'd do an outer join, just in case rows are missing, sow we don't wind up omitting rows.)

Something like this:

```
SELECT d.dt + INTERVAL -i.n MONTH + INTERVAL -1 DAY  AS last_date
     , SUM(IFNULL(t.tot_type_5,0))                   AS rt_type_5
     , SUM(IFNULL(t.tot_type_7,0))                   AS rt_type_7
  FROM ( -- first day of next month
         SELECT DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -DAY(DATE(NOW()))+1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 MONTH AS dt
       ) d
 CROSS
  JOIN ( -- thirteen integers, integers 0 thru 12
         SELECT 0 AS n
         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
         UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8
         UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL SELECT 12
       ) i

 LEFT
 JOIN ( -- totals by month
        SELECT CASE WHEN A.date < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -14 MONTH
               THEN LAST_DAY(     DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL -14 MONTH )
               ELSE LAST_DAY( A.date )
               END                                    AS _month_end
             , SUM(IF( B.type = 5 , B.amount , NULL)) AS tot_type_5
             , SUM(IF( B.type = 7 , B.amount , NULL)) AS tot_type_7
          FROM A
          JOIN B
            ON B.id = A.B_id
         WHERE B.type IN (5,7)
         GROUP
            BY _month_end
      ) t
   ON t._month_end < d.dt

GROUP BY d.dt + INTERVAL -i.n MONTH + INTERVAL -1 DAY
ORDER BY d.dt + INTERVAL -i.n MONTH + INTERVAL -1 DAY DESC
```

---

The design is meant to do one swoop through the `A JOIN B` set. We're expecting to get about 14 rows back.  And we're doing a semi-join, duplicating the oldest months multiple times, so approx . 14 x  13 / 2 = 91 rows, that get collapsed into 13 rows.

The big rock in terms of performance is going to be materializing that inline view query.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for explaining so well.I think Group By _month_end isn't giving the result i was looking for.. i wanted SUM until last month of last 12 months..  Thorsten Kettner's answer worked best for me.

Comment: Yah, the inline view query returns totals by month. That's only part of it. It's the condition in the semi-join of the outer query ( `t._month_end < d.dt` ) that causes the "by month" totals for *earlier* months to be combined. And that is the key to gaining performance, the outer query is adding up much smaller sets of pre-calculated monthly totals. The query pattern demonstrated in this answer satisfies the specification, and will work in MySQL versions earlier than 8

Answer (score 0):

You are getting some complicated answers. I think it is easier. Start with knowing we can easily sum for each month:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as monthtotal,
        type,
        MONTH(date) as month,
        YEAR(date) as year 
FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.B_id=B.id 
GROUP BY type,month,year
```

From that data, we can use a variable to get running total. Best to do by initializing the variable, but not necessary. We can get the data necessary like this

```
SET @running := 0;

SELECT (@running := @running + monthtotal) as running, type, LAST_DAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',1))
FROM 
(SELECT SUM(amount) as monthtotal,type,MONTH(date) as month,YEAR(date) as year FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.B_id=B.id GROUP BY type,month,year) AS totals
ORDER BY year,month
```

You really need to have a connector that supports multiple statements, or make multiple calls to initialize the variable. Although you can null check the variable and default to 0, you still have an issue if you run the query  a second time.

Last thing, if you really want the types to be summed separately:

```
SET @running5 := 0;
SET @running7 := 0;

SELECT 
    LAST_DAY(CONCAT(year,'-',month,'-',1)),
    (@running5 := @running5 + (CASE WHEN type=5 THEN monthtotal ELSE 0 END)) as running5, 
    (@running7 := @running7 + (CASE WHEN type=7 THEN monthtotal ELSE 0 END)) as running7
FROM 
(SELECT SUM(amount) as monthtotal,type,MONTH(date) as month,YEAR(date) as year FROM A LEFT JOIN B on A.B_id=B.id GROUP BY type,month,year) AS totals
ORDER BY year,month
```

We still don't show months where there is no data. I'm not sure that is a requirement. But this should only need one pass of table A.

Also, make sure the id on table B is indexed.

Comment: It's good that this answer noted that the query pattern does not guarantee that a row for each month will be returned. And yeah, that's an easier nut to crack. We should also note that the MySQL Reference Manual gives a specific warning about assigning and evaluating user-defined variables in the same statement; MySQL docs say behavior is undefined, which means the behavior is not guaranteed, but we do observe a consistent behavior with carefully crafted queries.